# Redirect the page if the print is successful - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
javascript:window.print();
document.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
```

I use above code to print a page I'm in then redirects it. What it does is it redirects the page if the print is successful or fail.

How can I redirect the page if the page is successfully printed only ?

Comment: Window.print() only shows a dialog. As far as I know it's not possible to get feedback from the printer with javascript. It only redirects when the dialog is closed and that can be both cancel and print (and even print does not guarantee success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I redirect the page if the page is successfully printed only ?

By giving the user a nice big clear link to follow if the print works. That's it. That's all you can do.

Even on browsers that support it (Firefox and IE), the [`onafterprint` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onafterprint) fires even if the user cancels the print dialog box, so it's completely useless. I, for one, would be really cheesed off with a web page I wanted to print if it redirected me somewhere else when I chose print, then canceled (for whatever reason) with the intention of going back to print it.

Then there's the whole issue of what "succesfully" means. Even if the user told it to go ahead and print, and the job got sent to the printer, that doesn't mean the printing was successful. Print queues notwithstanding, it's quite common to have to actually go back to the source and say "print" again when something goes wrong.

And then, there's the UX side of it. ***Even if*** the print was entirely successful, do you think a user really wants you to decide where they go next? No. Give them the option of going where you want them to go, but leave control in their hands — where it belongs.